# How to count words in a File when File has multiple spaces? - Java

Tags: java

I tried to implement the functionality of command "wc file name" in linux. 
This command counts the number of:

- lines
- words
- bytes

in a file.

Here is my code:

```
public class wc {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //counters
    int charsCount = 0;
    int wordsCount = 0;
    int linesCount = 0;

    Scanner in = null;

    try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("Sample.txt"))))){
        File file = new File("Sample.txt");

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

            String tmpStr = scanner.nextLine();
            if (!tmpStr.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                String replaceAll = tmpStr.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                charsCount += replaceAll.length();
                wordsCount += tmpStr.split(" ").length;
            }
            ++linesCount;
        }

    System.out.println("# of chars: " + charsCount);
    System.out.println("# of words: " + wordsCount);
    System.out.println("# of lines: " + linesCount);
    System.out.println("# of bytes: " + file.length());

    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that in a file there is text like this:

```
Hex Description                 Hex Description

20  SPACE
21  EXCLAMATION MARK            A1  INVERTED EXCLAMATION MARK
22  QUOTATION MARK              A2  CENT SIGN
23  NUMBER SIGN                 A3  POUND SIGN
```

There are multiple spaces with different lenghts. Sometimes doubled, sometimes more than that. How to refactor my code to be able to count words properly? How to get rid of multiple spaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) accepts a regular expression, so you can simply split on `\\s+` (multiple whitspace):

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String input = "Some input  with     more     than   one   space";
    String[] words = input.split("\\s+");
    System.out.println(words.length + " words");
}
```

Output:

```
7 words
```

See [on ideone.com](https://ideone.com/D0cOUL).

Comment: I used that method by creating tmpStr, replacing all multiplied spaces with empty string. Damn why I didn't noticed it...?

Answer (score 0):

`split` takes a regex too, so this should work:

```
tmpStr.split("\\s+")
```

Answer (score 0):

@Marvin has already suggested solution here.

This is another way of splitting the strings having multiple spaces.

> s.split("[ ]+")

should also work fine for you.

Example

```
String s="This is     my test    file.";
String s1[]=s.split("[ ]+");
System.out.println(s1.length);
```

Output:-

```
5
```